# ¿Cómo generar reportes con filas cruzadas?

Tags: sql-server, sql

Buenas,

tengo las siguientes tablas como parte de mi base de datos

[image: Tablas]
En este caso es un sistema de atención de tickets donde la tabla Ticket tiene como atributos TCKT_FFINAL que es la fecha que se registra automáticamente una vez se cierre el ticket, que a su vez está asociada a un OPERARIO (este es el que cierra los tickets).

Lo que busco es generar un cuadro de mando o un cuadro de reporte, es una página web donde al ingresar a la opción de Reporte Semanal se muestre automáticamente un cuadro con la semana actual como la que adjunto abajo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso sería el reporte de la semana actual donde la primera columna es el código de todos los operarios, sus nombres y a partir de la tercera es un conteo de los tickets atendidos por cada día de la semana.

El otro reporte que deseo obtener es el mensual, en este caso le pasaría una fecha a través de un DatePicker y que mi aplicación obtenga el mes actual y que elabore el reporte desde el primer día hasta el último.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy haciendo una consulta en SQL, pero leí que hay librerías o herramientas que te permiten hacer este tipo de reportes de forma más rápida y sencilla, la verdad es que no encuentro información especifica y recurro a ustedes para que me brinden su ayuda.

Uso Java JSP, SQL Server.

Comment: Cómo podríamos ayudarte con una consulta si no tenemos idea sobre cuál es la estructura de tus tablas y el resultado que esperas?

Comment: Hola Wil, Oye tu pregunta es muy general, debes ser mas puntual en tus preguntas. Parece que buscas que te entreguen todo un sistema. Puedes ir partiendo por problemáticas en especifico.

Comment: ¿Cómo sabemos que datos tienen tus tablas y que variables utilizas?

Comment: Gracias por sus sugerencias, acabo de editar el post. @AlfonsoCarrasco no busco un sistema completo, sólo quería una ayuda o base de como hacer mis consultas, gracias.

Comment: Aún con tu edición, no está claro lo que necesitas. La tabla bitácora se una con la tabla ticket con la columna tckt_numero?, cómo sabemos cuál es el estado que identifica que un ticket está cerrado?. Por favor, date el tiempo de escribir una pregunta completa con sus detalles

Comment: La tabla bitácora es la relación entre Ticket y Operario, tiene el número de ticket y el código del operario. Muchas gracias por tus correciones y tu tiempo en orientarme.

Comment: creo que tienes que usar un pivot table checa este link https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/communitydocs/servidores/sql-server/pivot-dinamico

Comment: Si entiendo bien, no estás buscando una consulta SQL. Mas bien, estás buscando herramientas para generar este tipo de reportes de forma automática. ¿Correcto?

Comment: En parte, consultándole a un profesor me comentó que existen herramientas como el CrystalReport que te permiten hacer eso, aunque por mi parte por desconocimiento opté por hacer una consulta en SQL, y pues necesito una guía :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Investigando un poco en la documentación de SQL Server, particularmente PIVOT, como alguien había comentado, logré generar este código que creo que puede ayudar:

```
CREATE TABLE Reporte
(
Operario_ID int, 
Operario varchar(50), 
Fecha date, 
Ticket int
)

INSERT INTO Reporte VALUES
(1, 'Luisa', '2016/01/01', 2),
(2, 'Roberto', '2016/01/01', 3),
(3, 'Gerardo', '2016/01/02', 1),
(4, 'Pedro', '2016/01/02', 2),
(5, 'Margarita', '2016/01/03', 4),
(6, 'Juliana', '2016/01/03', 3),
(1, 'Luisa', '2016/01/04', 1),
(2, 'Roberto', '2016/01/04', 4),
(3, 'Gerardo', '2016/01/05', 3),
(4, 'Pedro', '2016/01/05', 1),
(5, 'Margarita', '2016/01/06', 2),
(6, 'Juliana', '2016/01/06', 4),
(1, 'Luisa', '2016/01/07', 2),
(2, 'Roberto', '2016/01/07', 2),
(3, 'Gerardo', '2016/01/08', 2),
(4, 'Pedro', '2016/01/08', 1),
(5, 'Margarita', '2016/01/09', 2),
(6, 'Juliana', '2016/01/09', 1),
(1, 'Luisa', '2016/01/10', 1),
(2, 'Roberto', '2016/01/10', 4),
(3, 'Gerardo', '2016/01/11', 3),
(4, 'Pedro', '2016/01/11', 1),
(5, 'Margarita', '2016/01/12', 2),
(6, 'Juliana', '2016/01/12', 4)
GO


WITH ctePivot (Fecha, DiaSem, MaxFecha) AS
(
    SELECT Fecha, DATENAME(WEEKDAY, Fecha) AS DiaSem, MAX(Fecha) as MaxFecha FROM Reporte GROUP BY Fecha
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, Fecha), DATENAME(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(dd, 1, Fecha)), MaxFecha FROM ctePivot WHERE Fecha < MaxFecha
)

SELECT * INTO #Fechas FROM ctePivot

SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT Reporte.Operario_ID, Reporte.Operario, Ticket, DiaSem PivotDiaSem
    FROM #Fechas LEFT JOIN Reporte ON #Fechas.Fecha = Reporte.Fecha
) X
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Ticket)
    FOR PivotDiaSem IN ([Sunday], [Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday], [Saturday])
) P;

--DROP TABLE #Fechas
```

Ya sería ajustarlo un poco para que cubra tus necesidades.

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias compañero, fue de uno de esos ejemplos de los que me guié! :)